# How to trace and collect all used dependent JavaScript for a particular field

Tags: javascript, puppeteer, trace

I would like to gather  all events and JavaScript code with dependencies for a particular form field/all form field including frameworks. I have tried with puppeteer and CDP to get the events for a field and subsequently gather JavaScript. I was able to get events details successfully. Not sure how to walk all traces from the event to collect used JavaScript code. Quick help appreciated.

Following code has been used to collect events.

```
listener = await windowHandle._client.send('DOMDebugger.getEventListeners', {
objectId: submitElementHandle._remoteObject.objectId
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another variant, more hacky and less reliable.

```js
import puppeteer from 'puppeteer';

const browser = await puppeteer.launch(/* { headless: false, defaultViewport: null } */);

try {
  const [page] = await browser.pages();

  // Hook on setting listeners.
  await page.evaluateOnNewDocument(() => {
    window._puppeteerListenersMap = new Map();
    const _puppeteerOldAddEventListener = EventTarget.prototype.addEventListener;

    EventTarget.prototype.addEventListener = function newAddEventListener(...args) {
      const element = this;
      const [eventName, eventListener] = args;

      if (!_puppeteerListenersMap.get(element)) {
        _puppeteerListenersMap.set(element, Object.create(null));
      }
      const allListeners = _puppeteerListenersMap.get(element);
      allListeners[eventName] ??= [];
      allListeners[eventName].push(eventListener);

      _puppeteerOldAddEventListener.call(this, ...args);
    };
  });

  await page.goto('https://example.org/');

  // Test setting listeners.
  await page.evaluate(() => {
    document.body.addEventListener('click', function click() {
      console.log('addEventListener click');
    });
    document.body.addEventListener('dblclick', function dblclick() {
      console.log('addEventListener dblclick');
    });
    document.body.onclick = function onclick() { console.log('onclick'); };
    document.body.ondblclick = function ondblclick() { console.log('ondblclick'); };
  });

  // Test getting listeners.
  const data = await page.evaluate(() => {
    const element = document.body;
    const elementListeners = Object.create(null);

    const allListeners = _puppeteerListenersMap.get(element);
    if (allListeners) {
      for (const [eventName, eventListeners] of Object.entries(allListeners)) {
        elementListeners[eventName] = eventListeners.map(
          eventListener => eventListener.toString()
        );
      }
    }

    for (const name in element) {
      if (name.startsWith('on') &&
          element[name] !== null &&
          typeof element[name] === 'function'
      ) {
        elementListeners[name] = element[name].toString();
      }
    }

    return elementListeners;
  });
  console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, '  '));
} catch (err) { console.error(err); } finally { await browser.close(); }
```

Output:

```
{
  "click": [
    "function click() {\n      console.log('addEventListener click');\n    }"
  ],
  "dblclick": [
    "function dblclick() {\n      console.log('addEventListener dblclick');\n    }"
  ],
  "onclick": "function onclick() { console.log('onclick'); }",
  "ondblclick": "function ondblclick() { console.log('ondblclick'); }"
}
```

UPD. Testing for the page from codepen:

```js
  // Test getting listeners.
  const data = await page.evaluate(() => {
    const element = document.querySelector('#signup_v1-email');
    element.value = 'foo'; // Input invalid email.

    const elementListeners = Object.create(null);

    const allListeners = _puppeteerListenersMap.get(element);
    if (allListeners) {
      for (const [eventName, eventListeners] of Object.entries(allListeners)) {
        elementListeners[eventName] = eventListeners.map(
          eventListener => (
            eventListener.call(element, new Event(eventName)), // 'not a valid email' in Browser console.
            eventListener.toString()
          )
        );
      }
    }

    for (const name in element) {
      if (name.startsWith('on') &&
          element[name] !== null &&
          typeof element[name] === 'function'
      ) {
        elementListeners[name] = element[name].toString();
      }
    }

    return elementListeners;
  });
```

Comment: Yes, you are on point. This returns specific script, how do we ensure whether it returns proper script. I mean, How do we execute returned script using puppeteer to trigger/test it.  
**Example**  
**JQuery on change event in code**  

`$('#signup_v1-email').on("change", function () {
                if (!validateEmail($('#signup_v1-email').val())) {
                    alert("not a valid email")
                }
})`  
**Puppeteer scrapped code**  

`function(b){return typeof o!==U&&o.event.triggered!==b.type?o.event.dispatch.apply(a,arguments):void 0}`

Comment: Would like to execute the collected script using puppeteer, for JQuery event handler code it seems like a different code. Can you help?

Comment: @SuriyanSuresh It is hard to say without the URL of the page. And I do not know jQuery( Maybe there are some event handlers attached to the element and the one used by jQuery is attached not via `addEventListener()` or `.on..` property under the hood. Can you share the URL and the element selector so that I can try to test?

Comment: Here is my codepen https://codepen.io/suriyansuresh/pen/VwWjqmp , just check the JQuery onchange event. In JS Editor, just check my custom code after line 790 (unable to link jquery validation via cdn)

Comment: @SuriyanSuresh I've downloaded the code and tested it locally. If I understand correctly, jQuery wraps event handlers in some minified code, so it is unrecognizable, but it is the same by its behavior. In test part, I added `element.value = 'foo';` and then replaced `eventListener => eventListener.toString()` with `eventListener => (eventListener.call(element, new Event(eventName)), eventListener.toString())` to call the handler before the serialization — and I've got the expected `'not a valid email'` in the browser console.

Comment: Thanks for your effort. can you pls share your test via codepen?

Comment: @SuriyanSuresh I've added the modified tedtin part at the end of the answer. 2 added lines are marked by comments.

Answer (score 1):

This is all I can get from the [Chrome DevTools Protocol documents](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/):

```js
import puppeteer from 'puppeteer';

const browser = await puppeteer.launch();

try {
  const [page] = await browser.pages();

  const cdp = await page.target().createCDPSession();
  await cdp.send('Debugger.enable');

  const scriptIdToUrlMap = new Map();
  cdp.on('Debugger.scriptParsed', ({ scriptId, url }) => {
    scriptIdToUrlMap.set(scriptId, url);
  });

  await page.goto('https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/DOMDebugger/');

  await page.waitForSelector('body > main');
  const { objectId } = (await cdp.send('Runtime.evaluate', {
    expression: 'document.querySelector("body > main")',
  })).result;

  const { listeners } = await cdp.send('DOMDebugger.getEventListeners', { objectId });

  for (const listener of listeners) {
    console.log('Listener details:', listener, '\n');

    console.log('Script URL:', scriptIdToUrlMap.get(listener.scriptId), '\n');

    const { scriptSource } = await cdp.send('Debugger.getScriptSource', {
      scriptId: listener.scriptId,
    });
    console.log(
      'Script source start:',
      scriptSource.split('\n')[listener.lineNumber].slice(listener.columnNumber),
      '...\n',
    );
  }
} catch (err) { console.error(err); } finally { await browser.close(); }
```

Current output:

```
Listener details: {
  type: 'click',
  useCapture: false,
  passive: false,
  once: false,
  scriptId: '4',
  lineNumber: 181,
  columnNumber: 649
}

Script URL: https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/scripts/index.js

Script source start: (){I.classList.contains("shown")&&(I.classList.remove("shown"),P.focus())}document.addEventListener("keydown",e=>{e.metaKey||e.ctrlKey||e.altKey||(e.keyCode>=65&&e.keyCode<=90&&document.querySelector("cr-search-control").inputElement.focus(),"Escape"===e.key&&I.classList.contains("shown")&&I.classList.remove("shown"))}),P.addEventListener("click",e=>{e.stopPropagation(),I.addEventListener("transitionend",()=>{O.focus()},{once:!0}),I.classList.add("shown")}),B.addEventListener("click",W),O.addEventListener("click",W); ...
```

Comment: @SuriyanSuresh Well, if it is minified jQuery in 1 line, this code can only give the rest part from the handler start in the whole file. I cannot find a way to get just the handler code in the docs.

Comment: Might be a way to get the instance of the function and logging its definition.